# WPF Create and save Inline text outside of the main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, emoji

I want to store my own Emojis before using them in a (Rich)TextBlock.
Now it does not allow me to create a Windows.Controls.Image outside of the Main thread...

```
  private static void AddEmojiToString(List<Inline> block, BitmapImage source)
    {
        var textRun = new Run("");
        System.Windows.Controls.Image emoji = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        emoji.Height = 15;
        emoji.Width = 15;
        emoji.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        emoji.Source = source;
        block.Add(new InlineUIContainer(emo));
    }
```

Is there any way to run this code outside of the main thread? I just want to prepare and store the text to be able to display it later. 
Everything works fine if called from the Main thread.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: As a [DispatcherObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks), an Image element has thread affinity. It can only be accessed from the thread where it was created.

Comment: So does that mean that its impossible to bind to a List Inline, pretty much like a string? I don't know of any other way to use Emojis in WPF.

Comment: What about using XAML with bindings?

Comment: Well I store some Items and these Have some properties and a few strings which contain Emojis. Everything is done with bindings, the problem is when i try to "prepare" the Inline string ("text with emojis" or howerver its called :D). I got it to work by calling the method with Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {/* your code here*/})); 
but it somehow just does not feel right :D